# Update database with JSOn string asp.net MVC4

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Hey I am trying to post a form to my controller as Json and then update the database where columns match. I can't seem to get it to work. I am using a function as shown below to convert the form data into a json string and it's posting through but I'm having trouble with the controller method I need to find out how to match the valuse in the json with the values in the database any help would be great

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    url: "Admin/update/",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formToJSON(),
    success: function (themessage) {

    }
});
```

Converting form with JSON.stringify

```
function formToJSON() {
 return JSON.stringify({
    "username": $('#username').val(),
    "fname": $('#fname').val(),
    "lname": $('#lname').val(),
    "address1": $('#address1').val(),
    "address2": $('#address2').val(),
    "postcode": $('#postcode').val(),
    "town": $('#town').val(),
    "memcat": $('#memcat').val(),
    "phone": $('#phone').val(),
    "email": $('#email').val(),
    "message": $('#message').val(),
    "password": $('#password').val(),
    "Admin": $('#Admin').val(),
 });
}
```

Post contains

```
{"username":"Broon","fname":"Paw","lname":"Broon","address1":"12 Glebe Street","address2":"Sinderins","postcode":"DD12 4RT","town":"Dundee","memcat":"Ordinary","phone":"123456","email":"paw@localhost","password":"paw","Admin":"no"}
```

Controller Method
    //
        // POST: /Admin/

```
    public JsonResult update(string username)
    {



        var themessage = from b in db.member
                         select b;


        themessage = themessage.Where(b => username.Contains(b.username));

        foreach (var item in themessage)
        {
            item.username = username;
        }


        db.SaveChanges();


        return Json(themessage, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The problem is accessing the json data to match the database data. I'm guessing I may need to parse the json some way? Above I have only tried to match the username.

Comment: You are expecting a string as method parameter but you are posting the entire Object.

Comment: Do you know how I can access the objects params?

Comment: You should create an object that matches the JSON that you are sending, and use It as parameter!

Comment: Sorry I'm a little lost could you explain or show how to do this?

Comment: what they are suggesting is creating a model with username, fname, lname, etc as parameters in that model.  then your input to the action would be that model instead of the string.  then you can access the parameters as model.username

Comment: Thanks I got it working using the JSON object